# Which algorithm can i use to identify relevant parameters in my database?

Tags: algorithm, parameters, data-mining

I have a database with 14 parameters (X1-X14) that were obtained from an EEG, i need to apply a few classification algorithms to determine if the sample is from a Male or Female volunteer, but first need to remove the features that give me useless data. 
The parameters are like B,C,D as shown below:

[image]

Can someone help me?
Thank's

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection

Comment: I do not quite understand what do you need. Just delete something from the database or analyse the EEG data?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider looking at the different feature selection class from [sklearn.feature_selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_selection) module. I encourage you to go through this [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html). Since your data is categorical, you can use [chi-squared](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html) test. You don't need to remove useless features beforehand, any feature selection methods like chi-squared approach would do that for you.

Additional resources:

- [Feature selection for machine learning in python](http://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-machine-learning-python/)
- [Feature selection: diving into data](http://blog.datadive.net/category/feature-selection/)